# How to set class="active" to the active page

Tags: java, jsp

I'm designing an application in which I'm using jsp pages. Now I need something that indicates which is the current page that is being displayed. Basically, I want a menu that has  for every page, on which I place  class=”active” on the current page.

How do I do this? Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Kickoff example:

```
<c:set var="currentPage" value="${fn:substring(pageContext.request.servletPath, 1, -1)}" />
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${bean.menu}" var="item">
        <li><a href="${item.link}"${item.link == currentPage ? ' class="active"' : ''}>${item.name}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This assumes `${bean.menu}` to be a `List<Menu>`, the `Menu` to be a bean with properties `link` and `name` and the `${item.link}` to return pathnames like `home.jsp`, `contact.jsp` (or if you're using a controller servlet, `home`, `contact`, etc).

The [`fn:substring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/substring.fn.html) gets rid of the leading slash. The conditional operator `?:` in EL only prints the class when the condition is true, else nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the current URL

```
<% String URL = request.getRequestURL(); %>
```

Then in the menu you could set the class="active" on an element if the current URL (or, retrieving the 'current page' from the url) match the menu element (by title, id...) you want to be "active"

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work. I hope it helps when I post an example below on how it is now: 
<c:if test="${role == 'ROLE_EMPLOYEE' }">
  <li><a href="calendar.htm?perso=1${roleAtt}">
    <img src="<c:url value="/img/calendar-icon.png" />" alt="cal" width="20" height="20" class="icon" />
    <spring:message code="menu.Calendar"></spring:message>
  </a></li>
</c:if>